# Added Custom field in User Meta, but it does not display on output

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I had create a custom fied that named **sience_step** by function `my_user_contactmethods` in the file **functions.php** of my theme to set into the user profiles an additional field with some info.

Function code to set the field in the users:

```
function my_user_contactmethods($user_contactmethods){

  $user_contactmethods['sience_step'] = 'Sience Step';

  return $user_contactmethods;
}
```

But when I try to get the value of the created field on the page - nothing happen (**container has create**, but not get `author_meta`). Maybe some know how to solve this bug?

I'm using the next code with function `get_the_author_meta` to get it:

```
<div class="sience_step">Step: 
  <?php echo get_the_author_meta('sience_step', $key->ID); ?> // not work
</div>
```

**Update:**

P.S.
I want to admit that the standart author_meta fields, like `'description'` showed normaly by such html code:

```
<div class="sience_step">Step: 
  <?php echo get_the_author_meta('description', $key->ID); ?> // all work
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to save the options before showing them on front end. Your function only shows the new field on Profile page. You can go through this link for the complete process. It shows the whole process step by step.

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

**Edit:** For your scenario you just need to put this piece of code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'sience_step', $_POST['sience_step'] );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code, but it does not help... sience_step field still not display

Comment: DId you update profile field page after adding this code ? You need to save the value once before it shows

Comment: You code is work. This is my mistake, because I have a strange error with  fields output. For strange reasons the template get all info by get_athe_uthor_meta() function from admin profile, not from current author page...

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy Coding.